# iOS load data from a .plist file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I am new to iOS development. Currently, I am trying to get data from a .plist file and showing on **UITableView**. While running the application, Xcode didn't provide any error, But my application shows nothing but this

[image]

Here is my code

**TestAppTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestAppTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *content;

@end
```

**TestAppTableViewController.m**

```
#import "TestAppTableViewController.h"

@interface TestAppTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestAppTableViewController

@synthesize content = _content;

- (NSArray *) content{
    if (!_content) {
        _content = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]];
    }

    return _content;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.content count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"city"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"state"];
    return cell;
}
```

**Data.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>New York</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>NY</string>
        <key>cityText</key>
        <string>This is the description of the city that goes in the tex view just testing.</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>Los Angeles</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>CA</string>
        <key>cityText</key>
        <string>This the second item&apos;s textview</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>Chicago</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>IL</string>
        <key>cityText</key>
        <string>here is the text view description for the third item.</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>Sandiago</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>CA</string>
        <key>cityText</key>
        <string>Here is another city from california</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>Talahasy</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>FL</string>
        <key>cityText</key>
        <string>Talahasy is the capital of the florida state.</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>Boise</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>Idaho</string>
        <key>cityText</key>
        <string>boise is the capital of idaho and i have no idea where that is.</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I didn't able to figure out the problem. So, my question is what is the problem in my code ? How can I show the data from plist file ? I browsed the previous question's in stackoverflow but that didn't helped me.

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTableView you are returning 0?

Comment: @Yasir you need to parse the plist data and then load it into tableview. check whether you array have information or not once. Use Json parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tableview needs at least one section-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;// make this 1
}
```

also try using objectForKey instead like this (although its automatically invoked if key doesn't start with @ according to documentation) and type cast to be sure.

```
cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = (NSString*)[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"state"];
```

If you are still getting nothing then it would be worth checking that content actually contains the plist data. In your **-(NSArray *)content method**, before you return it may be worth logging the count of **_content**. Also confirm that **self.content = _content**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here, you should return 1 or any number you want except 0:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController:UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableDataSource>
```

just see your plist you are inside of array you can use dictionary. so implement like below code it help you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFilename" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    // Having outlet for tableArray variable.
    tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:contentArray copyItems:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [tableArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   // In your case dictionary contains strings with keys and values. The below line returns dictionary only. not array..
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [tableArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return dictionary.allKeys.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *dictionaryOfArray = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *keysArray = dictionaryOfArray.allKeys;
    cell.textLabel.text = [keysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dictionaryOfArray valueForKey:[keysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```